# 2 Separate user accounts in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I m wondering if it is possible to have 2 separate accounts for django/python. I have a user(CLIENT) account but also looking to have a service provider account with a a login on the same project. Is this possible and what is the best method?

Comment: Of course it's possible, just create another account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the default User for django by 
inheriting from AbstractUser

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
  #Boolean field to check if client or service provider
  is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_serviceprovider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  # Give other fields
```

Then in the settings.py ,add

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.User'
```